# Music for the entire New Year

Tags: riddle

I know about this disk jockey, J. Jason. He plays same track every year, over and over again and just started his play list again. He never plays venues. His music can only be listened to on the radio, both on FM and on AM as well. Can you guess the play list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This playlist must be:

> the **months of the year**.

Since...

> **J JASON DJ FM AM** (all elements from the text, since 'DJ' is an abbreviation for 'disc jockey') represents the initial letters of the English months in order, starting from June: **J**une, **J**uly, **A**ugust, **S**eptember, **O**ctober, **N**ovember, **D**ecember, **J**anuary, **F**ebruary, **M**arch, **A**pril, **M**ay.

This explains why his playlist just started again:

> It's January 1 - a new year has begun and the cycle of months has begun again!

Comment: ROT13 Lrnu, gung'f jung V gubhtug gbb ohg V fgvyy qba'g frr gur pbaarpgvba jvgu "Ur arire cynlf irahrf." vs rire gurer vf bar...

Comment: @oAlt I believe that's purely set-up for the FM/AM quip, no further significance of its own

Comment: @Stiv you are quite right. As an afterthought, I could have obscured it a bit more by replacing FM/AM with the corresponding wave bands but nevertheless you've already answered it.